# How long do seasons last?

Tags: kittens-game

In the Kittens Game, how long (in real life minutes) do seasons last?

Comment: Testing this now. What I have discovered is that the game seems to run slower if you switch to a different tab.

Comment: A random test (while active) gave a 100 day season, with 2 seconds days (so 200 seconds for season). But it's only a quick and very incomplete test.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After I researched the code, this is what I found out.

```
//how much ticks are performed per second ( 5 ticks, 200 ms per tick)
    rate: 5,
```

so 5 ticks per second.

```
dayPerTick: 0.1,
```

that means 2 seconds for 1 day.

```
daysPerSeason: 100,
```

100 days per season.

If you multiply 100 days times 2 seconds you get 200 seconds

So to answer your question:

200 seconds for 1 season.

3.33 minutes for 1 season.

Comment: Much better answer than I was going to post. I'd like to add that @Studoku on the main question is right - the game runs slower in the background, and the 'use web worker' option to prevent that doesn't seem to work on Chrome. My workaround is to open Kittens Game in another window, so my kittens can starve in realtime while I browse elsewhere.

Comment: @Nathan Yes indeed, that's rather annoying. When I'm at home I'll try took search some more in the code. I'm kinda curious.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [the game wiki](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Game+Mechanics#Basic_Units_of_Time) we can extend this info to longer and shorter lengths of time:

```
Unit of time |  Ticks  | Real Time
-------------+---------+-----------------------------------
Day          |      10 | 2 secs
Season       |    1000 | 3 mins 20 secs
Year         |    4000 | 13 mins 20 secs
Cycle        |   24000 | 1 hr 20 mins
Decade       |   40000 | 2 hrs 13 mins 20 secs
Century      |  400000 | 22 hrs 13 mins 20 secs
Millennium   | 4000000 | 9 days 6 hrs 13 mins 20 secs
```